# Dynamic Table content in HTML page using C socket programming

Tags: html, c, forms, sockets, browser

I am trying to do a sort of IoT project in which different clients (web browsers) connect to a web server (programmed in C by me using sockets in Linux). Each request in the server produces a "son process" that takes care of each client. Basically, the client asks for information contained in a list from a .csv file (where each line of the list corresponds to a certain time) by submitting the period of time desired. The list has sensor measurements per line (sensor ID, temp, humidity and time) and the number of measurements is not limited, there could be a million if you want.

My approach to achieve this is:

1.- The web server sends an HTML form so the client fills in the limits of the span of time desired, and these are sent via sockets.

2.- The web server receives the time limits and searches on my list the info (lines) within the period of time desired. The search is done in another code I made, it works, just notice that I use message queue as the IPC mechanism, so the server receives one line (message) at a time, and then the message structure is overwritten with the next line values.

3.- The web server sends back the list with every line so the client sees the info he has asked. There could be thousands of lines, so I believe I need to publish one line as they keep coming from the message queue.

I could make steps 1 and 2, but not 3. I don't seem to find a way to add the lines of info requested (ideally in a form of table) to the already sent web page with the form to the client. The simplified coding of the SERVER is the following:

```
 void main (void) {

 //Socket creation and definition 
 while(1)
 {
  client_socket=accept(server_socket, ...)
  if(!=fork)   //son process takes the browser request
     {
      write(client_socket, webpage, sizeof(webpage)-1);
      //webpage is a char containing the HTML form

      Then, I receive the time limits and search the lines of info needed
          while(//I still receive new line from message queue)
          { msgrcv (new line from file);
            write(client_socket, new row, sizeof(new row)-1)
            //new row should be a string with an HTML table row. THIS IS THE PART THAT DOES NOT WORK 
           }
      }
  }
}
```

So the problem is that I don't know how to add rows of info while I keep receiving messages from the message queue. When a localhost client (me) provides the time limits, then the page refreshes and I don't get any response from the server. I am a newbie programming, this is hard to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *If* you want to use the HTTP protocol you might want to read in detail about its concept and how it works *before* trying to use it. So an answer to this question would need to explain all this, therefore I am voting to close this question as *way* too broad,

Comment: Start your readings with [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) and continue until you learned what you need with reading the RFCs 7231, 7232, 7233, 7234 and 7235.

Comment: I have read as much as I could. You can at least wait for a few days (maybe someone can *really* help me) and then start voting against it.

Comment: After having received the time limits, let the server send a page header and send the table header, then each time the server receives a message send a table row. When there are no more messages send the table footer and the page footer. Let the server shut down and close the connection.

Comment: I have done exactly that, but I found that the submit button refreshes the page, thus not letting me "add rows" to the page. I am still researching a way to avoid refreshing the page. Any ideas?

Comment: See here for [the basics about forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) ...

Comment: .. and [this for the server side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps).

Comment: Thank you, it seems that I have to define the form action as "POST", to work with the info filled by the client.